# Can't boot --> PXE-M0F: Exiting Intel PXE ROM

Tags: 12.04, boot, bootloader, xen

Question:

I recently installed Xen (paravirtualization) on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine.
Ubuntu 12.04 worked excellently before, but afterwards, the trouble started.

The laptop crashed every time I closed down the screen.

Unsurprisingly, that resulted in file-system corruption.
Though the real trouble did not start until fsck complained about corruption and "repaired" it (I tried to abort it right away, but to no avail, Ubuntu wouldn't let me continue until I ran that damn more-trouble-than-worth program...).

The system run fine after a second restart (on the first restart, after some time, the file system switched to read-only for whatever reason...)

I afterward installed dist-upgrade (250 MB), to try to mitigate any trouble caused by corruption.

I restarted, it still worked fine.

I compiled bind9, latest version, compiling takes 15+ minutes, so I went to eat, meanwhile the laptop went into standby...

When I came back and tried to wake it, the screen remained black. Closing and opening the screen didn't help. As usual on the Xen kernel. So I switched off power, and on reboot, got the error message I am still fighting with right now:

```
Intel UNDI, PXE-2.0 (build 083)
Copyright (C) 1997 - 2000 Intel Corporation

For Atheros PCIE Ethernet Controller v2.0.2.3(05/18/10)

Check cable connection!
PXE-M0F: Exiting Intel PXE ROM.
No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key
```

The funny thing is, PXE Netboot is not enabled in my BIOS, so I shouldn't see this message.
Also, the BIOS boot-sequence is 1. USB stick - 2. HardDrive - 3. CD/DVD - 4. Network

I tried booting via the Ubuntu Live CD on a USB stick, and with that, I could access the data on my HardDrive, everything seems to still be there.

I ran the boot-repair tool, as recommended here

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
```

But that didn't help.
I still get the same error message on boot.
The good news is, the data seems to still be there...

Here is my boot-repair paste:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/1134895/

And that's it.
Anybody knows what I can do, short of copying down the data and reinstalling ?

To me it seems like Xen is in some strange boot state from the stand-by, and now tries to boot of PXE, which of course doesn't work, since there is nothing - fortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Oh man I get it working.</s>

For the record, if anyone has the same problem:

If you get this message (and your BIOS settings are OK):

1. Switch off your laptop for more than 30 seconds.
2. Start, and wait until you get to the error screen
3. press CTRL + ALT + DEL
4. Wait as it reboots, until you the the same error screen again
5. Press the power button and wait until it switches off.
6. Wait no longer than 5 seconds, and then press the power button
7. It boots to grub selection ! In grub, select "recovery" (because normal startup won't work)
8. Select "regenerate grub" or whatever it is called.
9. afterwards, select boot

**Edit:**
Diagnosis: HD defect